# Android: Quiz Application using if else statement

Tags: java, android

If Texboxt = " "

nextActivity.show

else msg = "Sorry!"

Can anyone help and tell me how to make this in Android eclipse java?

I have a code here, but I don't know how to correct this.

```
private EditText inputtxt;
private Button btnNext;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_g1);

    inputtxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View ContentView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String name;

                  name=inputtxt.getText().toString();

                 if (name.contentEquals("Accounting"))
                  {

                        Intent myIntent = new Intent (ContentView.getContext(), NextActivity.class);
                        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

                  }
                 else
                  {  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sorry, wrong answer. Try Again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }     

        });
}


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.g1, menu);
        return true;        
    }
```

`

Comment: What error/exception are you getting?

Comment: more clarification needed...

Comment: i think `if (name.equals("Accounting"))`

Comment: @NitinSethi , I add the brackets and semi colon as the application requested. But when I run it, it says "Unfortunately, Activity has stopped."

Comment: Paste your crash logs here.

Comment: [I uploaded the LOG CAT here.](http://judyannvibal.tumblr.com/post/63127214008/log-cat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your code like following it might work..

```
private EditText inputtxt;
private Button btnNext;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_g1);

    inputtxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View ContentView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String name;

                  name=inputtxt.getText().toString();

                 if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Accounting"))
                  {

                        Intent myIntent = new Intent (QuizActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
                        startActivity(myIntent);

                  }
                 else
                  {  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry, wrong answer. Try Again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }     

        });
}


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.g1, menu);
        return true;        
    }
```

Comment: I added brackets and semi colons as the system requested but I run it on the emulator, It says Unfortunately, Activity has stopped.

Comment: please paste error stack trace..nd what about device? is it running o.k on device?

Comment: `
                  else
                   {  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry, wrong answer. Try Again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }     

         };
         });
 }`

I add the brackets and semi colon as the application requested. But when I run it, it says "Unfortunately, Activity has stopped."

Comment: Have You declared `NextActivity` in Android Manifest File? i think something wrong in your brackets map open and close brackets closely..may b u have added unnecessary or missing one of them.

Comment: yeah, I think so too. But I don't know what to do and how to correct it. I am really a newbie in android programming, I just explore and search for tutorials, but it rarely give me what I really need. Thanks for your answer. Please help me.

Comment: There's something wrong in the code not in its manifest because when I delete the codes in java and run it, it shows the output design of the activity.

Comment: You can see the logCat [here](http://judyannvibal.tumblr.com/post/63127214008/log-cat)

Comment: Logcat showing NullPointerException in onCreate()..so either builder unable to find laoyut(setContentView()) otr 1 of the activty..

Comment: In my observation, there's a problem with the code. Because whenever I delete the codes, it perfectly shows the activity.
Do you see any mistakes in the construction of the code?
I'm really in need to correct this and finish the codes as soon as possible, thank you for answering it really help me.

Comment: HI :)

thank you for your code, the only missing in the CODE is 
    **btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);**

Someone helped me out to this. Thank you ^_^

Comment: oh..silly one..i just forgotten...i reviewed many times..:(..thx.

Answer (score 0):

Change To:

```
if (name.length()==0)
  {
     Intent myIntent = new Intent (ContentView.getContext(), NextActivity.class);
     startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

  }
  else
  {  
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sorry, wrong answer. Try Again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare your string with this

```
   if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("Accounting"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("Accounting"))
```

instead of

```
if (name.contentEquals("Accounting"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `startActivityForResult(intent)` will open a new activity and the previous activity waits for a result from the new activity. Use Bundle to share message between the activities and use     `startActivity(intent)` instead of `startActivityForResult(intent)`

Answer (score 0):

```
     if (value.equals("")) {
        Log.e("value equal to zero", value);
    } else {
        Log.e(value, "value not equal to zero");
        startActivity(new Intent(Registernew.this, next.class));
        finish();
    }
```